# combining requirejs requests into one request

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs

I am using require JS on a project.

I have a several modules.

Lets assume that each module has two or three files that make up the module.

I know I can use the module optimizer to optimize this.  However, I would still be left with one file per module.  If I'm loading 10 modules.. I will still have 10 files.

How can I make one request for this?  I'm looking for a way to turn require(1.js, 2.js, 3.js) into a request like jsloader.php?q[]=q.js&q[]=2.js&q[]=3.js etc.

I can create the php file that combines the JS.. but how can I make requirejs request something like this?